# How to select an action based on user ID in web page using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to compare the Id from excel with the table in the system. If the both Id are same then it will select an action in the table.
It will go to the next page until it find the user Id and select the action process. It looks like my code are wrong but I don't know which part that I need to change.

```js
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("S")).click();
        String author = sh1.getRow(5).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
    String id = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/thead/tr/td[2]")).getText();  
    do {
        if(id.equals(author)){

            Select view = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//select[@name='selectedAction'])")));
            view.selectByVisibleText("View");
            driver.findElement(By.id("returnImage2")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).click();
            driver.close(); 
            break;

        }
        else {
            driver.findElement(By.id("imgListNext2")).click();  }

    }
    while(!id.equals(author));


    }
}
```

This is the screenshot for the table. So based on the ID in the excel which i put as an (author) then it will compare the ID in the table (User ID).

[image]

Comment: Do you see any error? At which line? What does the error says?

Comment: wasn't a runnable code snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First please check that the element ids you can using are same for the current page and the next page, if not then you need to pick new ids for every page you are on and you can take a boolean which will change to true if your condition matches and till the condition is not met you can continue to check it using a while loop, like:

```
boolean match = false;
while(!match){     
  if(id.equals(author)){
  //Insert the select code here and set the boolean as true like:
  match = true;
  }
  else{ 
  driver.findElement(By.id("imgListNext2")).click();
  }
}
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: looks like the id was not being compare, the system keep on click the next page.

Comment: I guess you xpath for that element is incorrect, can you send whole div hierarchy for it so that i can help you with the xpath

Comment: ya i think the xpath is wrong, i try to put the xpath for the table and print out the text. it shows the whole data in the table but why it still cant read the right id. I cant copy the html.

Comment: Can you please take the screenshot of the whole div structure and upload it on imgur and then share the url of it ? I would see the structure and help you with the xpath

Comment: i think i can share the screenshot but no the url because the system only can be accessed using the company network

Comment: Please share the screenshot then and let me know what is the field/text you want to get from that xpath

Comment: Please get the xpath as `WebElement userId = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='tblInfo']/thread/tr/td[2]"));
` then assign it to a string by taking the getText() like `String id = userId.getText()` and now use this string to check your if condition. It should work

Comment: It shows an error this Unable to locate element: //table[@class='tblInfo']/thread/tr/td[2]

Comment: Please use this xpath: `//table[@class='tblInfo']/thead/tr/td[2]` Sorry i made a typo in the last xpath

Comment: Sorry but xpath get the text of "User ID" not the data in the table of "User ID". Maybe i need get the data for User ID column first.

Comment: Yes you need to get the data from your excel and then match it with the ui data. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 0):

You are testing id == author twice (once in `if` and once in `while`) and you aren't pulling the ID off the page on each new page since it's outside the loop. Something like this should fix it

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("S")).click();
String author = sh1.getRow(5).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
while (!author.equals(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/thead/tr/td[2]")).getText()))
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("imgListNext2")).click();
    // you will probably need to add some sort of wait here... wait for stale or the like to make sure the page has changed before you pull the ID again in the while
}

Select view = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//select[@name='selectedAction'])")));
view.selectByVisibleText("View");
driver.findElement(By.id("returnImage2")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).click();
driver.close();
```